# typedef or using keyword when exposing external library class in my namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef, using-statement

I want to expose a class from an external library to my library's users.  Specifically I want to 'import' the class to my namespace so that the user does not need to know what libraries I am using behind the scenes.  Often it seems that I can either do this by using a `typedef`, or by simply `using` the class.  Is there any reason for choosing one method over the other (or doing something else)?  (I seem to have some gaps in my education :) )

For example:  I want to create a serial port manager that uses Boost::Asio.

```
namespace MySerialManager {
  //should I use a typedef
  typedef boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control flow_control ;
  //or a using...
  using boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control;

  class SerialManager 
  {
    //let the user specifify the flow on construction
    SerialManager(const flow_control& fc);
  }
}
```

or should I be doing something else altogether....  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to "import" a class template, then `using` would be your only option. As it stands, I don't think there's any substantial difference. Personally, I'd go for typedef in the above case, because it's an older and more familiar construct.

Comment: Cool thanks, I find myself doing one or the other and was anxious I was going to get caught out one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

Both have the same end result. using is maybe the more close to your intent.